# How to write ouput of git fsck into a file

Tags: command-line, git

I use git 2.43.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

Within a git repo i run this command in the terminal:

`git fsck`

and the output is:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (309003/309003), done.
Verifying commits in commit graph: 100% (1/1), done.
```

Now I want to have this output appended to an existing logfile.
I have tried all of these possibilities but none works! The logfile stays empty.

```
git fsck 2> git.log
git fsck &> git.log
git fsck >> git.log 2>&1
```

Unbelievable that this is so hard to achieve. Solutions?

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  This is *community* support; 16.04 is EOSS thus out of community support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution.

The missing part was the `--progress` option. The Progress Output is not written to the output per default!

`git fsck --progress > git.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

From `git fsck --help`

> --[no-]progress
> Progress status is reported on the standard error stream by default when it is attached to a terminal, unless --no-progress or --verbose is specified. --progress forces progress status even if the standard error stream is not directed to a terminal.

Using `git fsck --progress 2> git.log` does what you're asking for.